# Google Chrome Inspect devices failed

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I faced some situation where the web app I developed worked differently (with errors) in a portable device than in computer. Then some googling took me to Inspect device feature of Google Chrome. After successfully connecting the phone to PC, I just clicked the `inspect` link for the corresponding tab.

Some internet resources said that some appspot link must be accessible. And, I verified it too. It is accessible from PC.

One mentioned try to open another inspect element window from the momentary devtool window by hitting `Ctrl + Shift + I`. It worked once out of many times and closed after a few seconds.

## Configuration

**Development system:** Chrome 51.0.2704.19 dev-m (64-bit) running on Windows 10

**On Device:** Chrome 49.0.2623.105 running on Android 4.4.2

PS: Please, comment if any additional resources required to solve this issue

Comment: What happened after you clicked on Inspect link for the tab? What isn't working?

Comment: I get an empty window which stay loading for a second or two and then disappears